# Can I read time data from an RTC (Real-Time Clock) chip without a microprocessor?

Tags: clock, rtc

I have an HD146818 (Motorola MC146818) integrated circuit, which is a real-time clock. I would like to build a simple clock on it, which will control an 8-segment display. I read the datasheet for this chip and it is not clear to me whether the chip can operate independently without a microprocessor. My assumption is that time information such as hours, minutes, and seconds, etc. are stored in the HD146818, and access to them, i.e. reading, is done through the address pins A0-A7 (pin 15 "high"), taking into account the appropriate configuration of other pins for data reading. I assume that I can decode the A0-A7 pins (from binary to BCD) and read the time. Is this possible?

https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/555707/HitachiSemiconductor/HD146818/1

Comment: Hate to be a smart a** here, but... why?! Even basic MCU can do all those things, like initialize RTC, read its data, convert to 8-segment, setup alarms, read and debounce buttons for setting time/alarm, generate waveform for alarms and many more. All without additional chips or discrete components. Cannot be simpler than that.

Comment: @Maple 1. Because I don't write a code (yet) 2. because I like to experiment with an old school digital logic chips :)

Comment: That is fair, and something I used to do too. May I point out, however, that with some devices (and this RTC is one of them) the amount of logic chips and interconnections between them requires schematic design that becomes indistinguishable from writing logic expressions for MCU. This is exactly the project where electronics and software merge.

Comment: @Maple Yes, I understand that. I just want to make it simples as possible. To start the chip with setting up registers, read the A0-A7 and decode the data into a nice, visible form - 8 segment display. Thanks.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki but the point that maple made was that you still end up with something that requires you to write code - just that's it's not code for a well -understood programming language for a microcontroller, but a code that controls your own custom very complicated state machine. (It might not be textual code, but pages full of drawings and tables and timing diagrams.) That is the exact opposite of "simple as possible". There's a reason microcontroller exist, and it's that they make this exact kind of thing orders of magnitude easier than building things in logic hardware yourself :)

Comment: Turning it around, this is simply the wrong chip for the application you want to build. This chip was designed specifically to be easy to interface to an MPU. You're creating an uphill battle for yourself by trying to avoid that. More to the point, there are other chips with the same functionality that are designed to be connected directly to displays. If you want a "simple" project, you should start with one of those.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks Marcus for clarification. I think I get the point now. I'm wondering fi I can this work with my Analog Discovery 2? There is a pattern generator which allows me to send/receive informations with digital circuits. So creating a BUS I could set the pattern to initialise the chip. Am I right? How the pattern should lok like? as a one of the timing diagrams Fig. 1,2,3? or something else?

Comment: An analog discovery is a measurement/actor device to be attached to a PC or other controller, right? No, that doesn't solve any of the problems you have, you need a controller.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think Jerzy can do it with the device he's speaking of -- the pattern generator of [documentation](https://digilent.com/reference/test-and-measurement/analog-discovery-2/reference-manual) seems more than capable for this.

Comment: @jonathanjo I'm a bit confused – can the analog discovery2 autonomously talk to an RTC chip, and calculate which parts of a display to light up? That doesn't sound like the functionality of a pattern generator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ... All I meant was I think you could get the bus signals out of the pattern generator and look at the results with the logic analyser function of that device.  For sure, it doesn't look like it's going to do the display driving and for sure it's not autonomous in the sense that you need your computer to drive the whole thing.  Also, For learning what the signals are like it might be a good tool.  For driving it for real it would be excessive.  And of course, *much* more complex a device than a microprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this chip operates as a kind of "magic RAM" -- *once you have it started*.

Note in particular the process for setting the time involves writing to "Register B"; and having the correct divider selected in Register A.  If you can make the right signals without a microcontroller, this chip will certainly work.

It's certainly possible to do it with a state machine, if that's what you want to do.

---

Edited to add

> "However, in this diagram, both reading and writing occur simultaneously... this seems impossible?"

They have just presented both timings on a single diagram, which can be confusing to read.  (The Intel timings are shown on two diagrams 2 and 3; similar but slightly different.  You choose whether you want to do the Motorola-style or the Intel-style, both will work.)

**READ** When you read from the chip, you make `R/W` high.  You put the address on `AD` and take `AS` low: the device latches the address. You disable your outputs, and then after you make `DS` high, after T<sub>DDR</sub> the device will put its data on the `AD` bus (shown in red) and you read it.
[image]

**WRITE** When you write to the chip, you make `R/W` low at the appropriate time, and put the data you want to write on the `AD` bus.  When you take `DS` low the device will read the data.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. what do you mean by "If you can make the right signals without a microcontroller, this chip will certainly work." I understand that I need to start it first. Is the setting of the registers done through the A0-A7 pins? Or other ones?

Comment: You set the starting values by writing to RAM (yes, through AD0-7), having set the registers. (see fig 15 and text above it.)  By "Make the right signals" I mean eg fig 1 etc which is how you read/write to the device.  Your logic must produce AS, DS, R/W etc.

Comment: As I understand it, I need to reproduce the timing diagram from figure 1. However, in this diagram, both reading and writing occur simultaneously... this seems impossible? How can I provide these sequences so that data is first written and then read?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. The chip keeps time with a battery even when MCU is turned off.

However, There is a but.

You would need to connect to the bus and create that bus logic with logic chips, FPGA or CPLD which allows you to initialize the chip, set time and read the time for displayig it.

It is certainly not impossible, and a neat idea, but I don't see why would anyone even bother to try it in practice.

It will of course depend on if you are already an expert working with logic at that level, but most people would likely write a few lines of program code instead.

Now, if you really want to make a clock, you would likely buy an easy to program MCU board, where the MCU already contains a built-in RTC, so you don't even need to use that RTC.

Comment: Thanks. "You would need to connect to the bus and create that bus logic with logic chips, FPGA or CPLD which allows you to initialize the chip, set time and read the time for displayig it." - do I need to initialise it once?

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki Yes but you need to decide if you want battery backup or not, and if you do, then your "logic" needs to check if the chip just started from full power-off state without correct time or is it already previously initialized and ticking with correct time. That may not be the main point of the logic you want to design.