# What is the application of the 74LS373?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, ttl

Looking at the truth table, the data from the D(n) input are directly transferred to the Q(n) output when the high state appears at the C (CLK) input. If there is a low state, there are no data at the output. The operation of this circuit is simply a switch with the possibility of setting it to a high impedance state. Am I right? Am I not seeing some function for which this circuit was invented?

Comment: The '374 is a flip-flop, the '373 is a latch.

Comment: In passing, yes, this is the right kind of device to use for interfacing with the RAM chip of your other [recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674774/can-i-read-time-data-from-an-rtc-real-time-clock-chip-without-a-microprocessor).  You use it to put the address on the AD bus and then be tristate when you are reading data.

Comment: @jonathanjo Thank you for pointing that out, I was just thinking about it in the same way.

Comment: Also take a look at 74xx244 which just does tristating without the latching function, which might also suit putting the address onto a bus.  For reading the results there is 74xx377 which just does latching, suitable where you never need to tristate the output.

Comment: It also stores the data when the Clk is not high. That means it's a memory unit! Quite a lot more useful than just a switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an 8-bit latch. It's main use was separating data and address busses while maintaining the address. In old CPU designs. 8086/8088 for example has an ALE line that was connected to the latch enable of the 74373. This way, the address is valid, even when the bus is now used for data.

Answer (score 2):

The primary function is as a **latch** -- it stores the inputs.  Additinoally, it's one with tri-state **output enable**, so we can put the output on a bus.

The classical way to use these is, for example, to latch inputs, as in a parallel input port: several devices are connected with all the matching Q joined (Q1 to Q1, Q2 to Q2) and all the D to various inputs.  When desired to latch the data, the CLK is triggered -- perhaps all devices at the same time.  But then one is read by having its OE enabled.

The other way is to use two, back to back: Q1 to D1, to implement a bidirectional port.

[image]
From [TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct373.pdf))